# snmp agent libraries for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, snmp

I have to implement a performance statistics  MIB for a linux based device and I am looking for a good agent development library. I came across net-snmp and agent++ libraries. I am looking for easier to understand and robust library. Which is the best library if usability and robustness is main criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [net-snmp](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/). It is robust and works well. The API is in C but quite simple to encapsulate. More than a library and APIs it is a well tested set of tools to handle SNMP. A reference. I don't know agent++. It is perhaps simpler to deal with as it seems to be a C++ lib.

my2c

Answer (score 3):

I used [Agent++](http://www.agentpp.com/) and it worked great. They have a tool to automatically creates C++ code to manage a MIB.