# Need a simple SNMP library c++

Tags: c++, snmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easy to use SNMP client library for c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249062/easy-to-use-snmp-client-library-for-c)

I just started my first programming job, my first task is to research, and eventually implement, a way to collect data about how the user is using the product, and send the data periodically to a host where it can be read and analyzed. I am told the best way to implement this would be using SNMP. I'm coding in C++, and after a day of research, I can not find a suitable solution on my own. Which SNMP library would be best for my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249062/easy-to-use-snmp-client-library-for-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116516/snmp-agent-libraries-for-c-c/3116583#3116583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The de-facto standard implementation is net-snmp, as stated in the comments. I do not know of any C++ wrapper around it. Someone mentioned SNMP/Agent++ and other libs in the [linked answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249062/easy-to-use-snmp-client-library-for-c), but I have not tried them ...

My two cents

Comment: I've looked int net-snmp, and it seems like a suitable solution. Now my problem is installing it. I've downloaded the source files for version 5.7, but now I'm lost. any help / advice?

Comment: It depends on your platform :)

Comment: Windows 7, Visual studio 2010...